# efcore 2.2 turn off proxy creation for a specific query when Using LazyLoadedProxies

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have an application where in most places I want to be able to use the LazyLoadedProxies so am calling UseLazyLoadingProxies in OnConfiguring.

There are specific queries that I don't want proxies as I am going to serialize the object and others where it may be passed to another part of the application and I don't want any N+1 errors so want to ensure that I am not getting a Proxy.

How can you disable Proxies for a specific query.

Comment: Note that even without lazy loading you won't necessarily escape reference loops if the model has bidirectional relationships.

Comment: @TanvirArjel I just rolled back your edit to the name of the question as you completely changed the meaning of the question.  LazyLoading and Proxies are two separate things.  You can have LazyLoading without Proxies.

Comment: @runxc1BretFerrier Sorry! I have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want any N+1 errors so want to ensure that I am not getting a Proxy.

No! you cannot disable proxy creation in EF Core query. But for **JSON serialization** you can turn it off as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(
            options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );

    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried that and it had no affect.  I still received a Proxy class.

Comment: @runxc1BretFerrier I have updated my answer! Please check it.